# Timezone, Time setting in Linux using shellscript

Tags: linux, timezone

I really need your help on a job of setting timezone and time on a router using Linux OS **remotely from Web**  ( Linux OS based on Linux Kernel 2.6.30).
For fulfilling this job, I use CGI and Shellscript. Below are steps:

1. Get Time, Timezone info from Browser
2. Execute CGI to set time (using C)
3. CGI executes Timezone_Setting shellscript

Here is what I'm doing for the script in step 3:

The parameter($1) is one of the following string (A):
"GMT-12", "GMT-11", "GMT-10",..."GMT", "GMT+1",.. "GMT+12".

It seems that I can use the following to set timezone:

**`ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Japan  /etc/localtime`**

**Questions:**
1) Am I doing the right way?
2) How can I use the command above with my A strings correctly?

Note:
In the above command, "Japan" is one of the files in my "/usr/share/zoneinfo" directory. 
And I can do a conversion before using the command like:

```
"GMT-9" <-> Japan

"GMT-5" <-> EST
( etc. )
```

but It seems not the good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to set the timezone depends on what C library your router uses. With [Glibc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library), the C library used on non-embedded Linux systems, `/etc/localtime` is a symbolic link to a file under `/usr/share/zoneinfo`, or a copy of one. With [uClibc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UClibc) (the one my home router uses), the time zone information is in `/etc/TZ` and is stored as a `TZ` environment variable specification (see below). Check which method your router uses. If your router uses Glibc, your approach looks correct.

`GMT+9` and `Japan` are different time zones. `GMT+9` means a time zone that is always 9 hours ahead of GMT. `Japan` means whatever time it is in Japan, taking [DST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) and any past and future time zone change in Japan. Oh, and `GMT-9` the wrong way round.

If you only need the timezone to be set in a particular program, run it with the [`TZ` environment variable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html#tag_08_03) set to the timezone name or specification. For example, a timezone specification for the current DST rules of most Western Europe countries looks like this:

```
TZ=CET-1CEST,M3.5.0/2,M10.5.0/3
```

meaning the timezone is called `CET`, corresponds to UTC+1 (i.e. CET - 1 = UTC), and the timezone is CEST (with a default +1 hour offset) between the last Sunday of March at 2am and the last Sunday of October at 3am. For a simple year-round offset, you can use a setting like

```
TZ='<GMT+9>-9'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is there any way to set TZ depending only on GMT+/-. I meant I don't care about the country but only "GMT-12"->"GMT+12". Something likes: if I set time to 10:00:00 and GTM+1=> I assume the current time: 9:00:00 in GTM+0

Comment: @sees I've updated my answer to describe the `TZ` environment variable, it should do the trick.